# Why does this Spam Code run unlimited times?

Tags: python

Got an exam in python in two days, pretty basic stuff.
This is the code given in an exercise

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
spam = spam + 1
```

I would have expected it to run until it hits 5 (so with the +1 given in the last line 2 times) But the answer is "Unlimited times".

Anyone knows why? :) Is ir because there is no `elif` condition in this example?

Comment: You need to move the `spam` increment inside the loop. Indent it.

Comment: Think about how blocks and indentation work in Python. Is the `spam = spam + 1` assignment really inside the loop?

Comment: As a general suggestion (for your exam too), ask yourself "what value does this variable have at this point in the program? Repeat stepping through lines until you find the issue

Comment: move `spam = spam +1` in while loop

Answer (score 3):

In python, indentation matters. Try this:

```
spam = 0
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
    spam = spam + 1
```

If you don't ident the line `spam = spam + 1` Python will interpret it as being out of the `while` block, therefore it is not executed and it stays on an endless loop.

Comment: Hello Lucas, Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down the code line by line.

First you have

```
spam = 0
```

This sets the variable `spam` equal to the value `0`. And it will always stay that value until explicitly changed by the code.

Then we have a while loop

```
while spam < 5:
    print('Hello, world.')
```

This literally means while the value of `spam` is less than 5 keep calling `print('Hello World')`. However, spam is equal to 0, so it being smaller than 5 is true and will always be true. This loop also does not change the value so the loop will run indefinitely.

Finally, we have

```
spam = spam + 1
```

This staments increments `spam` by 1, but the problem is that this statement is never reached! I.e. it is placed after a loop that runs indefinitely!